# smtp client and accessing username and password from configuration code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I have mail settings inside web.config

```
  <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="&quot;testo&quot; &lt;admin@test.com&gt;" >
      <network host="mail.test.com" userName="admin@test.com" password="waiff75E-" port="25"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and if I'm using following code to send mail from c# code

```
smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
smtpclient.Send(mail);
```

how can I configure here to username and password from above configuarion code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the attribute `defaultCredentials="false"` to the `network` element so that it looks like:

```
<network host="mail.test.com" port="25" 
         defaultCredentials="false" 
         userName="admin@test.com" password="waiff75E-" />
```

The `SmtpClient` object will automagically initialize with whatever parameters you've specified in your configuration file (see the [Remarks section in the MSDN article for the `SmtpClient` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)):

> This constructor initializes the `Host`, `Credentials`, and `Port` properties for the new `SmtpClient` by using the settings in the application or machine configuration files. […]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this below code snippet and credentials will take care by webconfig Add defaultCredentials="false" in webconfig

```
 public bool SendSupportEmail(string fromMailID, string toMailID, string subject, string body)
        {

            bool brv = true;

            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                //smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(fromMailID.ToString());
                message.To.Add(toMailID);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = body;
                log.Info("From Addres-> " + fromMailID.ToString());
                log.Info("To Addres-> " + toMailID);
                smtpClient.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("From Addres-> " + fromMailID.ToString());
                log.Info("To Addres-> " + toMailID);
                //log.Info("CC Addres-> " + EmailId);
                log.Error("Error:  " + ex.Message + "\nStrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                brv = false;

            }
            return brv;
        }
```